# Tracking purchases via dynamic button that redirects to outbound links

Tags: php, javascript, url, redirect, outbound

I need to track purchases on my site via a dynamic button that redirects to another sites.

The code:

```
<div class="buyproduct">
<a onclick="target='_blank'" href="<?php echo $this->product['from'];?>">

<img src="http://xxx.com/data/images/buy.jpg" alt="Buy!"/>                          
</a>
</div>
```

Everytime a user clicks on the button it redirects to another site outside mine.

For example if I click on a jeans and then in the buy button, it redirects to wrangler site.

I need to track everytime this happens and know exactly to what url the user is beeing redirected.

The site is in PHP and Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an intermediate page on your server, maybe something like (out.php). You could then redirect all traffic to the out.php page, do the processing there, and then redirect.

```
<a target="_blank" href="/out.php?url=<?php echo urlencode($this->product['from'])?>">
    <img src="http://xxx.com/data/images/buy.jpg" alt="Buy!"/>
</a>
```

`out.php`

```
<?php
$url = urldecode($_GET['url']);
/*
MySQL CODE TO PROCESS TRACKING
*/
header("Location: ".$url);
exit;?>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! I used this code and it doesn't work...I suppose something I'm doing wrong. created a file in root "out.php", inserted the code. Now if I click on the buy button it sends to a blanck page with the code "$url = urldecode($_GET['url']); /* MySQL CODE TO PROCESS TRACKING */ header("Location: ".$url); exit;"

Comment: Add PHP tags around the code, like above. You will also need to add your own MySQL code for tracking as well

Comment: ooops, forget to add code. Now it shows an error: The page is not redirecting properly

Comment: you must ensure that `$this->product['from']` is actually producing a URL

Comment: Thanks Samuel! now it redirects. Can I add something inside "mysql code to process tracking" to track with analytics? For example a blank 1px image?

Comment: if you output anything in the source code then you will need to use javascript to redirect the URL. I would save the information that you need to a database.